# How to use getIntent and startActivity in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

The code like the following is in `Activity` , it will call `setAppLocale` function.
After call the `setAppLocale` function , it will `finish();` and restart by `startActivity(intent);`

The code in Activity

```
setAppLocale(mLocales[i]) ;

Intent intent = getIntent() ;
finish() ;
startActivity(intent) ;
```

And now , I want to do the same thing in `Fragment` by using the `Button` like the following code.

And I have define `Activity activity = getActivity();` in this Fragment.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainActivity.setAppLocale(mLocales[1]);

        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

But it crash and the error log is like the following:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(19694): Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm(19694): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416cc450)

--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
E/AndroidRuntime(19694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19694): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.Control.LanguageSettings$3.onClick(LanguageSettings.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(19694):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  568):   Force finishing activity tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer/.MainActivity
```

The code at **LanguageSettings.java:85** is `Intent intent = activity.getIntent();`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably do `Activity activity = getActivity();` before the fragment is attached to an activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do this in onActivityCreated

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
```

The reference to the activity is only available after the call of `onActivityCreated` so calling getActivity() after the call of this function will not return null.

Comment: It is working. I have to define the Activity activity = getActivity(); in onclick.  And can not only define in front of the code.